# IPython plots show up in IDLE

Tags: python, ide, ipython

This quite stupid, but every time i use `plot()` with IPython it pop's up in the IDLE window opposed to showning it inline. How can I change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `%pylab inline` when you are in the IPython shell. You may also specify `--pylab=inline` as an argument when you first launch IPython.

When you say "IDLE window", do you mean the Python IDE in the standard library?